# XML Schema Editor Recommendation

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl, xsd

I've been using Zend Soap Autodiscovery to create WSDL for my WebServices. After several months of work with this tool i find it insufficient. I've also found several opinions that i agree witch, which basicly sound like "Zend Autodiscovery is great tool for simple WSDLs but insufficient if u want something more accurate".

Basicly it lacks such features as:

- enumarations
- minOccur, maxOccur
- regular expressions

Which could help with removing a lot of unnecessary logic from my PHP code.

I've worked with some Java tool that included logical and physical view (according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_Editor) of XSD file.

Could you recommend some good tools for that? Would be great if they were free for commercial use, but if it's worth a price I would consider paying for it.

Best regards and thank you in advance for any suggestions.
Maciej

Comment: Are you looking editor where you can manually modify your WSDL/Schema or are you looking for a tool that generates a WSDL and schema from code? If you are looking for the first, you should change your question title (to something like "XML Schema Editor Recommendation").

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I'm looking for manual XSD/WSDL editor with graphical view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [OxygenXml](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) for authoring XSD files. It's got nice intellisense and it's easy to generate sample XML from your XSD. If you are authoring XSLT files, it is (in my opinion) the best product on the market as it's got great intellisense, syntax highlighting, and debugging capability.
[XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) is probably the industry standard for authoring XSDs but is quite expensive.

For testing services, I usually use the free version of [SoapUi](http://www.soapui.org/) because it has nice test assertion functionality - however, it doesn't have intellisense when editing a test request. It is also possible to generate and test web service requests (based on a WSDL) in OxygenXML and XMLSpy.

Comment: Thank you, will read about this tool.

Comment: I've decided to use different tool, but your answer helped a lot in research!

Comment: @MaciejJaśniaczyk No prob. All tools have pros and cons.